# How do I force Windows line endings in Java app?

Tags: java, file, io

I have a Java app that writes to a file with:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
bw.write(line + lineTermination);
```

Line termination is defined as:

```
\r\n
```

I get the odd, mysterious blank line inserted into my file.

I get no extra lines if I change my code to:

```
bw.write(line);
bw.newLine();
```

But I want to force a specific line ending, not use System property. Clients specifically request a line ending character - some even have |. Its not a viable fix to just use \n.

Here is an snippet of the data with missing line:

```
"KABE","14/01/11","14:35","14:56","1987","US","SS","CO","MARRIED WITH CHILDREN","","EINE SCHRECKLICH NETTE FAMILIE","","N","10","","12","O'NEILL ED","13","SAGAL KATEY"

"PRO7","14/01/11","14:35","14:55","2001","US","SS","CO","SCRUBS","","SCRUBS DIE ANFAENGER","","C","10","BERNSTEIN ADAM","12","BRAFF ZACH","13","CHALKE SARAH"
```

Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the line doesn't already have a line terminator? using `write("something" + "\r\n")` should force windows line endings.

Comment: String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator").toString();

Comment: As it turns out I only get this mysterious line break in gedit. Ive learnt my lesson and updated my text editor to gVim. My original code works as expected. I should know by now to ALWAYS try in another browser/editor/relevant application!!!! Palm to face moment :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
```

in order to set the system property inside your code.

Comment: Testing it independent of what I am setting as the system property for new line it still doesn't influence the way a string is written into, and only \n gives a new line. I am on Win and I was trying \r\n and the result is as that of only \n.

Comment: @Boro `BufferedWriter.newLine` uses exactly this property. "A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator." [see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

Comment: I agree it will set the character whatever you give when specifically called using `newLine()` but what I was expecting that it will also influence interpretation of String when writing it to a file. But I guess I wanted to much. :)

Comment: Is there not a way to force writing a \r without changing the system property for the entire application?

Comment: @Howard and others:  be advised that in the OpenJDK implementation, `newLine()` uses the value from `System.lineSeparator()`, which returns a cached value that in turn is read from the `line.separator` property **once** when the `java.lang.System` class is first loaded.  Changing the system property afterwards thus has no effect on `newLine()` although it will of course affect any method that reads the property on each call.  TL;DR:  Launch with `-Dline.separator=SomethingElse` if you want to change this.