# Specify line.separator as a compiler setting?

Tags: java, line-endings

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6128248/334862):

> You can call
>
> ```
> System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
> ```
>
> in order to set the system property inside your code.

it is quite easy to make a Java program output the desired line endings. However, I see no reason why one shouldn't be able to change that environment variable, say, as a compiler setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's simply not how [environment variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) work, by definition. Environment variables are dictated by the **runtime environment,** not by the compiler or any compile-time setting.

> Many operating systems use *environment variables* to pass configuration information to applications. Like properties in the Java platform, environment variables are key/value pairs, where both the key and the value are strings. The conventions for setting and using environment variables vary between operating systems, and also between command line interpreters.

Comment: but then could I possibly EXPORT=... something? Or is there just no way of altering this (given, of course, that the Java program itself does not alter it).

Comment: Of course. The `EXPORT` equivalent in Java is the `System.setProperty()` method call you already noted.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the correct name is? EXPORT whatwhat=\r\n?

Comment: Pass it as a JVM argument: `-Dline.separator="<crlf here>"`. You can get a CRLF on your clipboard on Mac systems with the following terminal command: `echo -en "\x0d\x0a" | pbcopy`