# Ensure Unix-style line endings used when generating XML on Windows with Java

Tags: java, xml, windows, line-endings

I am currently outputting an XML document to a file in Java as follows:

```
final Document xmldoc = toXMLDocument(docTheory);

// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmldoc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);

transformer.transform(source, result);
```

However, when run on Windows, this produces output with Windows-style line-endings.  I would like to have Unix-style line endings produced regardless of OS.  How I can do this?

Comment: i am not sure if thats the best solution for you but `string.replaceAll("\r\n","\n")` would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use LSSerializer rather than Transformer, you can use [LSSerializer.setNewLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html#setNewLine%28java.lang.String%29) to control newlines.

Comment: This doesn't work with java 6 and 7. https://community.oracle.com/message/6853346#6853346

Comment: It would be an answer, if you'd provide information, how to do XSLT transformation with LSSerializer instead of Transformer. Otherwise, it's a comment even if it somehow lead OP towards solution.

Comment: @DanubianSailor OP is not doing an XSLT transformation, he's using Transformer to serialize XML. Note the absence of a .xslt file in the Transformer configuration. There are plenty of examples for how to use LSSerializer online, I didn't think I have to repeat it.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between operating systems is because it is used internally the method `println` .
Before saving the file, change the line separator:

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
```

You could use a static block.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure if the classes you're using use the system properties, but if they do, this should work

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
```

[Related question but for Windows line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128174/how-do-i-force-windows-line-endings-in-java-app)

If not, you'll have to do as Foo Bar User said in his comment, replace them manually.