# How to control line endings that javax.xml.transform.Transformer creates?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am transforming a DOM document (org.w3c.dom.Document) to a Stream using

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, UTF_8.name());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult output = new StreamResult(out);
Source input = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

The document contains text nodes with linefeeds ('\n'). In the output they
are replaced with CRLF ("\r\n"), which is not desired. Is there a way to control this (besides replacing them afterwards, of course)?

I have no control over the documents DTD (-> XML whitespace handling).

(Remark: OutputKeys.INDENT is not the correct answer.)

Remark: Why this question is different from [question 19102804 (Ensure Unix-style line endings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102804/ensure-unix-style-line-endings-used-when-generating-xml-on-windows-with-java):

- This question refers explicitely to javax.xml.transform.Transformer and to the possibilities to influence its treatment of line endings. Question 19102804 asks for any solution, not only for one using javax.xml.transform.Transformer.
- Question 19102804 is limited to the task of getting "Unix-style line endings". In my case the ideal solution would be a component that justs puts out the DOM model instance as it is, not touching any node (what everything so far does).
- Changing the line.separator system property is not an option (see comment).

Comment: set the system property line.separator to \n

Comment: This may be possible, but it is not an option because it may break other code that relies on the correct value of that property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensure Unix-style line endings used when generating XML on Windows with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102804/ensure-unix-style-line-endings-used-when-generating-xml-on-windows-with-java)

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is serialize a DOM node then in the Java world you can use `LSSerializer` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) instead of a default `Transformer` and then you have the method `setNewLine` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html#setNewLine(java.lang.String)) to define or control your preferred line ending.

Comment: This is probably the best solution.  Gustave will need to change his transform destination to a [DOMResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMResult.html) to use this approach.

Comment: @VGR, I don't see why you need a `DOMResult`, the `LSSerializer` has a method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html#write(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput) to write to an `LSOutput` and that allows setting an OutputStream or a Writer.

Comment: The issue isn’t where the LSSerializer writes, it’s the input to the LSSerializer. Gustave wants to transform XML, and it’s the transformed XML that has the unwanted newlines.

Comment: With the use of `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()` you don't apply any XSLT stylesheet of your own that transforms the input XML, you only serialize the input XML. It is different when doing `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(someXslt)` but that is not shown in the posting.

Comment: Oops, you’re right.  I missed that he was using an identity Transformer.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: Thanks, that works! Do you know that it is impossible with Transformer?

Comment: The Sun/Oracle JRE uses a version of Xalan as the default Transformer, I am not sure whether it allows a configuration of the newline, if you use Saxon 9 instead then you can set http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/SaxonOutputKeys.html#NEWLINE.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution based on Martin Honnens answer. (But this is not exactly an answer to the question, which explicitely refers to Transformer. So probably the correct answer is "No.", but I'll leave that open for the moment.):

```
final DOMImplementationLS dom =
  (DOMImplementationLS) DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance().getDOMImplementation("LS")
;
final LSSerializer serializer = dom.createLSSerializer();
serializer.setNewLine("\n");
final LSOutput destination = dom.createLSOutput();
destination.setEncoding(UTF_8.name());
final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
destination.setByteStream(bos);
serializer.write(document, destination);
```

One difference between Transformer and LSSerializer is that the Transformer writes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

without inserting whitespace after, while the LSSerializer writes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and inserts a newline after.

Comment: Exactly. The question is about xslt transformation, and your answer is only about serializing xml. There's missing context how it answers OP's questsion.